# easyrsa: No such file or directory after make-cadir

Tags: 18.04, openvpn

I was told to do

```
sudo make-cadir /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
sudo du
cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
./easyrsa init-pki
./easyrsa build-ca
```

by [this manual](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-openvpn). Unfortunately I got

```
root@myhost:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa# ./easyrsa init-pki
bash: ./easyrsa: No such file or directory
```

Why and how to fix?

Comment: It looks like the version of easy-rsa in Bionic is 2.x aka [easy-rsa-old](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa-old) - the instructions you are following are for 3.x

Answer (score 0):

I think how easyrsa is installed has changed; certainly at one point that would have worked. You should be able to do this:

```
apt install easy-rsa
cd <directory you want easy-rsa>
ln -s /usr/share/easy-rsa/easyrsa easyrsa
```